# A JavaScript program to capitalize the first letter of each word in a given string - I don't understand this line of code

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm new to JS.
I've written a program that capitalizes the first letter of each word in a given string. I also found another piece of code on w3resource.com that does the same, but I don't quite understand how it works.
Here's my code:

```js
function capFirstLetters(str) {
  const words = str.split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const letters = words[i].split("");
    letters[0] = letters[0].toUpperCase();
    words[i] = letters.join("");
  }
  return words.join(" ");
}

console.log(capFirstLetters("i wrote a program that capitalizes the first letter of each word in a string."));
```

Here's the code from w3resource.com:

```js
function capital_letter(str) {
  str = str.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0, x = str.length; i < x; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);
  }
  return str.join(" ");
}
console.log(capital_letter("i wrote a program that capitalizes the first letter of each word in a string."));
```

What I don't understand is the line of code inside the for loop. Can you work with the letters of a string as elements of an array without first creating an array from the string?

Comment: Read the code line by line.  It takes the input `str` and runs `split()` on it.  Not sure what `split()` is? Check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split Now you have an array.

Comment: The answer is "Yes you can" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Useful_string_methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the other answers for the explanation of the split.

I answer your other question: Yes you can access the string as an array of letters.

However since a string is *immutable* (cannot be changed in place) we need to copy it anyway. Here I use [...spread] to make the array but I index the string directly

```js
const capFirstLetters = str => [...str]
  .map((letter,i) => (i===0 || ".?! ".includes(str[i-1])) ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter)
  .join("");

console.log(capFirstLetters("i wrote a program that capitalizes the first letter of each word in a string."));
```

Answer (score 0):

The split function, as described in [w3school documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), creates an array from a string. The following line creates an array variable called `str`, from the string variable called `str`, passed into the function - `capital_letter(str)`

```js
str = str.split(" ");
```

So in a console you could do this:

```js
str="i am a string";
```

Which returns:

```js
'i am a string'
```

and:

```js
str = str.split(" ");
```

Which returns:

```js
(4) ['i', 'am', 'a', 'string']
```

finally:

```js
str[3];
```

Which returns:

```js
'string'
```